# Php Events calendar with javascript/Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, calendar

I am on the final stage of building an events calendar for my website and this error has appeared **Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\calendar_start.php on line 38** Line 38 is `$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);` but i dont think the problem lies in there.

There are other pages of code but I don't think the error is because of them

Here is the code for calendar_start.php

```
<?php
$showmonth = $_POST['showmonth'];
$showyear = $_POST['showyear'];
$showmonth= preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $showmonth);
$showyear= preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $showyear);

$day_count = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $showmonth, $showyear);
$pre_days = date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, 1, $showyear));
$post_days = (6-(date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, $day_count, $showyear))));

echo '<div id="calendar_wrap">';
echo '<div class="title_bar">';
echo '<div class="previous_month"><input name="button" type="submit" value="Previous Month" onClick="javascript:last_month();"></div>';
echo '<div class="show_month">'  . date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $showmonth)) . ' ' . $showyear . '</div>';
echo '<div class="next_month"><input name="button" type="submit" value="Next Month" onClick="javascript:next_month();"></div>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="week_days">';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sun</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Mon</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Tues</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Wed</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Thur</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Fri</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sat</div>';
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
echo '</div>';

if ($pre_days != 0) { 
    for($i=1; $i<=$pre_days; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
    }
}
include ("connect.php");
for ($i=1; $i<= $day_count; $i++) {
    $date = $showmonth.'/'.$i.'/'.$showyear;
    $query = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM events WHERE evDate = "'.$date.'"');
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($num_rows > 0) {
        $event = "<input name='$date' type='submit' value='Details' id='$date'
onClick='javascript:show_details(this);'>";
    }
    echo '<div class="cal_day">';
    echo '<div class="day_heading">' . $i . '</div>';
    if($num_rows != 0) { echo "<div class='openings'><br/>" . $event . "</div>";}
    echo '</div>';
}

if ($post_days !=0) {
    for($i=1; $i<=$post_days; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
    }
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Also code for show_calendar.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="calstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function initialCalendar(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calendar_start.php";
    var currentTime = new Date ();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    showmonth = month;
    showyear = year;
    var vars= "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar"). innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function next_month() {
    var nextmonth = showmonth + 1;
    if(nextmonth > 12) {
        nextmonth = 1;
        showyear = showyear+1;
    }
    showmonth = nextmonth;
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calendar_start.php";
    var vars= "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar"). innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function last_month() {
    var lastmonth = showmonth - 1;
    if(lastmonth < 1 ) {
        lastmonth = 12;
        showyear = showyear-1;
    }
    showmonth = lastmonth;
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calendar_start.php";
    var vars= "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar"). innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function overlay() {
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
    el. = document.getElementById("events");
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
    el. = document.getElementById("eventsBody");
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
}
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function show_details(theId) {
    var deets = )theId.id);
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
    el. = document.getElementById("events");
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "events.php";
    var vars = "deets="+deets;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("events").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.get ElementById("events").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialCalendar();">
<div id="showCalendar"> </div>
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="events"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for events.php

```
<?php
$deets = $_POST['deets'];
$deets = preg_replace('#[^0-9/]#i', '', $deets);

include ("connect.php");

$events = '';
$query = mysql_query('SELECT description FROM events WHERE evdate ="'.$deets.'"');
$num_rows= mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($num_rows > 0) {
    $events.= '<div id="eventsControl"><button onMouseDown="overlay()">Close</button><br /><b> ' . $deets . '</b><br /><br /></div>';

    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $desc = $row['description'];
        $events .='<div id="eventsBody"> . $desc .'<br /><hr><br /></div>';
    }
}
echo $events;
?>
```

Comment: try this and see if there is an error mysql_query("YOUR QUERY") OR die("Error:".mysql_error()); this might answer.

Comment: where should i put it?

Comment: mysql_query('SELECT id FROM events WHERE evDate = "'.$date.'"') OR die("Error:".mysql_error());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query('SELECT id FROM events WHERE evDate = "'.$date.'"');
```

Is a built-in function which returns true or false (boolean as it is telling you).

So you are setting $query = boolean.

Try this:

```
$query = "Select id FROM events WHERE evDate = '$date'";
$num_rows = 0;
if($result = mysql_query($query)) {
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

Comment: (also, you should look into mysqli or PDO instead, it is more secure.)

Comment: fixed the initial error but now says "Notice: Undefined variable: num_rows in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\calendar_start.php on line 41"

Comment: @user3181157: you need to initialize the variable.  I will edit.  But if it isn't set, looks like your query isn't happening.

Comment: works now thanks for your help, i'll accept your answer in 2 minutes

Comment: I just finished editing. You also should have a $result variable.

Comment: If $num_rows is staying = 0, you should make sure you are properly connecting to the database.

Comment: do i still need to include if($num_rows > 0)

Comment: I would, because you might still get a $result and $num_rows might still be 0. So yes.

Comment: I still havent fixed to I need to declare $result earlier on or shoudl the code like that you gave me work straight out